# osx - Linking error, when building POCO library

Tags: c++, c, macos, poco, clang++

I'm trying to build poco library on osx 10.9 with clang++.
I'm running `make CXXFLAGS+=-stdlib=libstdc++ CFLAGS+=-stdlib=libstdc++ LDFLAGS+=-stdlib=libstdc++`.
It've successfully compiled all .o files:

> ** Compiling src/UUIDGenerator.cpp (release, shared) clang++  -Iinclude -I/Users/croco/Work/poco-1.6.0-all/CppUnit/include -I/Users/croco/Work/poco-1.6.0-all/CppUnit/WinTestRunner/include -I/Users/croco/Work/poco-1.6.0-all/Foundation/include -I/Users/croco/Work/poco-1.6.0-all/XML/include -I/Users/croco/Work/poco-1.6.0-all/JSON/include -I/Users/croco/Work/poco-1.6.0-all/Util/include -I/Users/croco/Work/poco-1.6.0-all/Net/include -I/Users/croco/Work/poco-1.6.0-all/Crypto/include -I/Users/croco/Work/poco-1.6.0-all/NetSSL_OpenSSL/include -I/Users/croco/Work/poco-1.6.0-all/Data/include -I/Users/croco/Work/poco-1.6.0-all/Data/SQLite/include -I/Users/croco/Work/poco-1.6.0-all/Data/ODBC/include -I/Users/croco/Work/poco-1.6.0-all/Data/MySQL/include -I/Users/croco/Work/poco-1.6.0-all/MongoDB/include -I/Users/croco/Work/poco-1.6.0-all/Zip/include -I/Users/croco/Work/poco-1.6.0-all/PageCompiler/include -I/Users/croco/Work/poco-1.6.0-all/PageCompiler/File2Page/include **-stdlib=libstdc++** -DNDEBUG -O2 -fasm-blocks -fPIC -c src/UUIDGenerator.cpp -o
>   /Users/croco/Work/poco-1.6.0-all/Foundation/obj/Darwin/x86_64/release_shared/UUIDGenerator.o

But when linking, `-stdlib` flag doesn't used and i receive some errors like this:

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>   "std::basic_string,
>   std::allocator >::data() const", referenced from:
>         Poco::UnicodeConverter::convert(std::basic_string, std::allocator > const&,
>   std::string&) in UnicodeConverter.o   "std::basic_string, std::allocator >::length() const",
>   referenced from:
>         Poco::UnicodeConverter::convert(std::basic_string, std::allocator > const&,
>   std::string&) in UnicodeConverter.o

What i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, my solution is to put `-stdlib` flag to `build/config/Darwin-clang` and configure build with required `Darwin-clang` config.